# How do I re-write this code for XYPieChart into Swift?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm trying to make a pie chart using XYPieChart in my Swift app, but I don't know how to retrieve the values using Swift. I have this code written in Objective-C, and need to write it in Swift.  Does anyone know how to do that?

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfSlicesInPieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart {
return self.values.count;
}

- (CGFloat)pieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart valueForSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
NSNumber* value = self.values[index];
return value.doubleValue;
}

- (UIColor *)pieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart colorForSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;    

- (NSString *)pieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart textForSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;    //optional
```

Answer (score 0):

`func numberOfSlicesInPieChart(pieChart: XYPieChart) -> NSUInteger`

`func pieChart(pieChart: XYPieChart, valueForSliceAtIndex index: NSUInteger) -> CGFloat`

`func pieChart(pieChart: XYPieChart, colorForSliceAtIndex index: NSUInteger) -> UIColor`

Use the above as a guide to do the last one yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how to set a value for the numberOfSlicesInPieChart or valueForSliceAtIndex, or any of those. How would I set them?

Comment: You don't know how to return a value from a function? I strongly suggest you study the Swift Programming Language book some more. Try `return self.values.count` and `return self.values[index].doubleValue`